# Unity Container 2 from 5 deprecated AddNewExtension

Tags: c#, unity-container

At Unity2 i would have this factory registers

```
     iocContainer.AddNewExtension<StaticFactoryExtension>()
        .Configure<IStaticFactoryConfiguration>()
        .RegisterFactory<string>("ApplicationPath", ioc => HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath);

     iocContainer.AddNewExtension<StaticFactoryExtension>()
        .Configure<IStaticFactoryConfiguration>()
        .RegisterFactory<string>("ApplicationUrl", ioc => ApplicationUrl());

     iocContainer.AddNewExtension<StaticFactoryExtension>()
        .Configure<IStaticFactoryConfiguration>()
        .RegisterFactory<string>("BaseUrl", ioc => BaseUrl());

     iocContainer.AddNewExtension<StaticFactoryExtension>()
        .Configure<IStaticFactoryConfiguration>()
        .RegisterFactory<RequestContext>(ioc => HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);

     iocContainer.AddNewExtension<StaticFactoryExtension>()
        .Configure<IStaticFactoryConfiguration>()
        .RegisterFactory<ApplicationContext>(ioc => ApplicationContext.GetForRequest());
```

Now this was deprecated, and only Register would take in place, but how could i register those factories ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for letting people know, the StaticFactory was replaced by the InjectionFactory, so

```
iocContainer.AddNewExtension<StaticFactoryExtension>()
        .Configure<IStaticFactoryConfiguration>()
        .RegisterFactory<string>("ApplicationPath", ioc => HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath);
```

would become

```
iocContainer
        .RegisterType<string>("ApplicationPath", new InjectionFactory(ioc => HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath));
```